# Iterate over an array of characters in steps

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hex characters that is > 8000 characters, and I need to do some operation on every 6 characters in the array.

Ranges in ruby have a really cool step feature:

```
(1..100).step(6) do //etc....
```

Is there any kind of functionality similar to this for arrays?

Something like:

```
string.split("").step(6) do //etc...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `Enumerable#each_slice`:

```
require 'enumerator' # if pre-Ruby1.9
string.split("").each_slice(6) do |ary|
  # ary is a 6-length array, and this is executed for every block of 6 characters
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed that one when I glanced over Enumerable

Comment: Note: OP says he has an "array of character", not a string. If you were going to iterate over characters of a string, you should use `string.chars.each_slice(6)`.

Comment: @Phrogz: I was just taking the lead off of his example. Good to learn about the `chars` method though, thanks for helping me learn something new :-)

Answer (score 3):

You say that you have an array of characters, but then you show code using `string.split("")`.

More efficient than using `split("")`—which will create an intermediary array of 8,000 strings before beginning, wasting both time and memory—use the [`String#chars`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chars) enumerator along with [`each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
string.chars.each_slice(6) do |a,b,c,d,e,f|
  # one variable for each character
end
```

or

```
string.chars.each_slice(6) do |a|
  # a is an array of all six
end
```

(Also note [`each_cons(6)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons), in case that's what you really meant.)

Comment: What is difference between `each_cons` and `each_slice`?

Comment: `each_slice(3)` would give `['a','b','c']` and then `['d','e','f']`, while `each_cons(3)` would give `['a','b','c']`, and then `['b','c','d']`, then `['c','d','e']`, etc.

Comment: Ah I see, No I definitely need each slice. Each group of 6 hex characters will correspond to 3 bytes in a binary file

Comment: @Hunter Oh! Are you sure you don't want [`String#unpack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-unpack) instead to turn your hex chars to bytes?

Comment: No need for this project because I am just going to copy paste into a hex editor. Thank you for the suggestion though

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.each_slice(6)`:

```
%w[a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p].each_slice(6) { |s| puts s.join(',') }
a,b,c,d,e,f
g,h,i,j,k,l
m,n,o,p
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a range with step, and `Array`'s method `values_at`. This method takes one or more integers, or a range as indices argument. Unfortunately `Range`'s `step` method doesn't return a range, but an enumerable. This can however simply be converted to an array of integers by prefixing an asterisk `*`.

```
string = "You could just use a range with step, and Array's method values_at."
step6 = (0...string.length).step(6)

string.split("").values_at(*step6).each do |char|
  puts char
end
```